# Control volume gain for Video/Audio stream in Firefox

Tags: firefox, audio, video-streaming, web-mediarecorder

I'm trying to record Video/Audio files using MediaRecorder API for Firefox.

When I'm using web Audio API for creating the nodes (source -> Gain -> Destination)

The output of the recorded file is only Audio as the return stream from the destination node is Audio stream only referring to this documentation 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode

Any suggestion for getting Audio/video stream in the destination output to record audio/video not audio only.

> ```
>     var mediastream;
>
>     var ctx = new AudioContext();
>
>     var mediaStreamSource = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(mediaStream); 
>
>     var destination = ctx.createMediaStreamDestination();
>
>     ObjectStore.VolumeGainNode = ctx.createGain();
>     ObjectStore.VolumeGainNode.gain.value = 0.5;
>
>     mediaStreamSource.connect(ObjectStore.VolumeGainNode);
>
>     ObjectStore.VolumeGainNode.connect(destination);
>
>     mediaStream = destination.stream;
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a stream composed of the gUM video track and your gain-modified audio track.

Following the standard, Firefox lets you modify tracks in a stream using `stream.addTrack` and `stream.removeTrack`, as well as compose new streams out of tracks with `new MediaStream([tracks])`.

This lets you solve your problem by replacing the gUM audio track with your gain-manipulated one:

```
var constraints = { video: true, audio: true };

var start = () => navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then(stream => modifyGain(video.srcObject = stream, 0.5))
  .catch(e => console.error(e));

var modifyGain = (stream, gainValue) => {
    var audioTrack = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
    var ctx = new AudioContext();
    var src = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(new MediaStream([audioTrack]));
    var dst = ctx.createMediaStreamDestination();
    var gainNode = ctx.createGain();
    gainNode.gain.value = gainValue;
    [src, gainNode, dst].reduce((a, b) => a && a.connect(b));
    stream.removeTrack(audioTrack);
    stream.addTrack(dst.stream.getAudioTracks()[0]);
};
```

Here's the fiddle (Firefox 44 or newer): https://jsfiddle.net/7wd2z8rz/

Again with MediaRecorder: https://jsfiddle.net/j33xmkcq/